# Java Thread Synchronization problem in same resource

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, producer-consumer

I am trying to operate on the same source with two threads. I designed a typical producer and consumer problem for it. While setting the value in the resource class with the producer, I want to get setted values with the consumer one by one. The output I want should be like this:

```
Producer -> Setting data = 0
Consumer -> Getting data = 0
Producer -> Setting data = 1
Consumer -> Getting data = 1
Producer -> Setting data = 2
Consumer -> Getting data = 2
Producer -> Setting data = 3
Consumer -> Getting data = 3
Producer -> Setting data = 4
Consumer -> Getting data = 4
```

Here is my Resource class:

```
public class Resource{
    
    private int value;
    private boolean current = false;
    public synchronized void setValue(int val) {
        while(current == true) {
        try {
            wait();
        }catch(Exception ex) {}}
        value = val;
        current = true;
        notifyAll();
    
    }
    
    public synchronized int getValue() {
        while(current == false) {
        try {
            wait();
        }catch(Exception ex) {}}
        
        current = false;
        notifyAll();
        return value;
    
    }
}
```

And main method and Producer,Consumer class is here:

```
    class Producer extends Thread{

    private Resource rs;
    public Producer(Resource rs1) {
        rs = rs1;
    }
    public void run() {
        for(int i = 0 ; i < 5 ; i++) {
            rs.setValue(i);
            System.out.println("Producer -> Setting data = " + i);
            try {
                sleep(100);
            }catch(Exception ex){
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        
    }
    
}

class Consumer extends Thread{
    
    private Resource rs;
    public Consumer(Resource rs1) {
        rs = rs1;
    }
    public void run() {
        int value = 0;
        for(int i = 0 ; i < 5; i++) {
            value = rs.getValue();
            System.out.println("Consumer -> Getting data= " + i);
            try {
                sleep(100);
            }catch(Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        
        
    }
    
}

public class Dependent {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        
        Resource res = new Resource();
        Producer p1 = new Producer(res);
        Consumer c1 = new Consumer(res);
    
        p1.start();
        c1.start();
        
    }

}
```

Although I use synchronized, wait and notifyAll keywords in the methods in the resource class, the threads continue to work without waiting for each other. Where am I making a mistake? I've seen a code sample similar to this code sample in a java book, there doesn't seem to be a problem.

When I write without adding the current boolean variable, the code doesn't even work. That's why I had to add it by looking from the book. Don't the threads need to work synchronously without checking the Current value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They *do* wait for each other, but the thread sync operations are much, *much* faster than Thread.sleep(100) so you can't tell. Your test code prints 'i' and not 'value', which is suspect. Get rid of `Thread.sleep(100)` in one of these threads (for example, in the consumer) and you'll find that the consumer nevertheless still requires about half a second to complete - as it will be waiting about 100 msec every time it invokes `.getValue()` on the resource, because that call will block (stuck in that wait() loop) until the producer calls .setValue which it only does about once every 100 msec.

Your Resource object 'works', for some value of 'works', but is very poorly designed, re-creating already existing and better implemented classes from the core library such as a `java.util.concurrent.Latch`, and which ignore interrupts and will blindly just keep waiting.

Their APIs are also a tad oddly named, in that a get call has considerably side effects. `get` is more of a `get and clear` operation: After a get operation, another get operation will freeze the thread forever, or at least, until some thread sets a value.

Answer (score 0):

How do you think?

```java
import java.io.IOException;

class Resource {

    private volatile Integer value;
    public synchronized void setValue(int val) {
        while(value != null && !value.equals(val)) {
            try {
                wait();
            }catch(Exception ex) {}}
        value = val;
        notifyAll();

    }

    public synchronized int getValue() {
        while(value == null) {
            try {
                wait();
            }catch(Exception ex) {}}

        int answer = value;
        value = null;
        notifyAll();
        return answer;

    }
}

class Producer extends Thread{

    private Resource rs;
    public Producer(Resource rs1) {
        rs = rs1;
    }
    public void run() {
        for(int i = 0 ; i < 5 ; i++) {
            rs.setValue(i);
            System.out.println("Producer -> Setting data = " + i);
            try {
                sleep(100);
            }catch(Exception ex){
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }

}

class Consumer extends Thread{

    private Resource rs;
    public Consumer(Resource rs1) {
        rs = rs1;
    }
    public void run() {
        for(int i = 0 ; i < 5; i++) {
            int value = rs.getValue();
            System.out.println("Consumer -> Getting data= " + value);
            try {
                sleep(100);
            }catch(Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }


    }

}

public class Dependent {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        Resource res = new Resource();
        Producer p1 = new Producer(res);
        Consumer c1 = new Consumer(res);

        p1.start();
        c1.start();

    }

}
```

or

```java
class Resource {
    private static final int WAIT_VALUE = -1;
    private volatile int value = WAIT_VALUE;
    public synchronized void setValue(int val) {
        while(value > WAIT_VALUE && value != val) {
            try {
                wait();
            }catch(Exception ex) {}}
        value = val;
        notifyAll();

    }

    public synchronized int getValue() {
        while(value == WAIT_VALUE) {
            try {
                wait();
            }catch(Exception ex) {}}

        int answer = value;
        value = WAIT_VALUE;
        notifyAll();
        return answer;

    }
}
```

Comment: I tried both of them but still same problems occurs. But why do I have to use while loop in both methods in Resource class. When I invoke them, I expect them to start without problem.

Comment: You want to display 0 0 1 1 2 2 or 0 1 2?

Comment: I redesigned my classes and problem solved. Thx for your help !